# How to disable Javers from creating Tables when starting application

Tags: javers

I am trying to work on an application which fails to start up due to Javers table creation errors(Issue is due to application DB problems). Is there a way I can prevent javers from creating tables during application start up (tables such as jv_commit)so I can work on the app while DBA fixes DB issues(this will take time)?

I have added following in application.yml, (not sure if its the right way to go)

```
  Javers:
           sqlSchemaManagementEnabled: false
           auditableAspectEnabled: false
           springDataAuditableRepositoryAspectEnabled: false
```

I have commented out @JaversSpringDataAuditable in all repository classes as well.

Javers dependency used

```
 <dependency>
                <groupId>org.javers</groupId>
                <artifactId>javers-spring-jpa</artifactId>
                <version>5.7.0</version>
            </dependency>
```

Error log

```
2019-10-16 16:51:32,796 25724 INFO  [main] o.p.core.schema.SchemaManagerImpl [SchemaManagerImpl.java:51] --- creating entity with name jv_commit using ddl:
CREATE TABLE jv_commit (
commit_pk NUMBER NOT NULL,
author VARCHAR2(200),
commit_date TIMESTAMP,
commit_date_instant VARCHAR2(30),
commit_id NUMBER(22,2),
CONSTRAINT jv_commit_pk PRIMARY KEY(commit_pk)
)  
2019-10-16 16:51:33,903 25724 WARN  [main] o.s.b.w.s.c.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext [AbstractApplicationContext.java:557] --- Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'javers' defined in class path resource [com/common/audit/JaversSpringJpaApplicationConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.polyjdbc.core.exception.SchemaManagerException: [DDL_ERROR] Failed to run DDL:
CREATE TABLE jv_commit (
commit_pk NUMBER NOT NULL,
author VARCHAR2(200),
commit_date TIMESTAMP,
commit_date_instant VARCHAR2(30),
commit_id NUMBER(22,2),
CONSTRAINT jv_commit_pk PRIMARY KEY(commit_pk)
)  
2019-10-16 16:51:33,935 25724 INFO  [main] o.s.o.j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean [AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:597] --- Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default' 
2019-10-16 16:51:33,938 25724 INFO  [main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource [HikariDataSource.java:350] --- HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated... 
2019-10-16 16:51:36,487 25724 INFO  [main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource [HikariDataSource.java:352] --- HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed. 
2019-10-16 16:51:36,493 25724 INFO  [main] o.a.catalina.core.StandardService [DirectJDKLog.java:173] --- Stopping service [Tomcat] 
2019-10-16 16:51:36,496 25724 INFO  [main] c.v.u.c.filter.AuditLoggingFilter [AuditLoggingFilter.java:195] --- in Filter destroy method 
2019-10-16 16:51:36,516 25724 WARN  [main] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase [DirectJDKLog.java:173] --- The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [RxIoScheduler-1 (Evictor)] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
 java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1093)
 java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 
2019-10-16 16:51:36,528 25724 INFO  [main] o.s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener [ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener.java:135] ---
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sqlSchemaManagementEnabled` switch is managed by the JaVers Spring Boot starter, see https://javers.org/documentation/spring-boot-integration/

If you don't use the starter the switch won't be read, but still you can set this switch when building a Javers instance:

```java
        def javers = JaversBuilder.javers()
                .registerJaversRepository(sqlRepository()
                .withConnectionProvider({ DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:mem:empty-test") } as ConnectionProvider)
                .withSchemaManagementEnabled(false)
                .withDialect(getDialect())
                .build()).build()
```

Comment: The change you have suggested worked with the code change. 

I also tried the approach of using JaVers Spring Boot starter along with the sqlSchemaManagementEnabled configuration in YML but is not working. 
  <dependency>
  <groupId>org.javers</groupId>
  <artifactId>javers-spring-boot-starter-sql</artifactId>
  <version>5.7.0</version>
 </dependency>
 
I'm trying this in order to avoid code related change to. Any suggestions?